# why first partition of sd card shoud be fat32?

Tags: omap

I am working on omap paltform. When we press power on reset button ROM code will search for boo-table partition i.e FAT32.

My question is why first partition should be FAT32 .
Can't we make first partition as ext2 or ext3?

Answer (score 2):

When an OMAP processor is reset is first runs a boot ROM masked into the chip.  One of the places this boot ROM can look for code is in a file named MLO in the first partition of an SD card.  But the boot ROM only understands FAT32.

See also http://omappedia.org/wiki/Bootloader_Project

Other processors based on Cortex-A cores have similar but different boot rules.